# laravel blade for and foreach with if loop maximum time

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, for-loop, foreach

I want to for loop 7,and foeach $time to blade.

if has $time foreach = for loop $i is output `<div>O</div>`, else is output`<div>X</div>`

but my code is trouble...  loop 35 time.

I want loop total maximum time of 7 times

if  $time = [3,6]

```
example output  :X X X O X X O
```

or if  $time = [ 1 , 2 , 4]

```
example output :  X O O X O X X
```

How can I do, Please help me, thanks~

blade.php

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
@foreach($time as $value)

@if($value->time == $i)
  <div>O</div>
@else
  <div>X</div>   
@endif

@endforeach
@endfor
```

Controller

```
public function interview()
{
    $time = Interview_time::where('bsinformations_id',5)->get();
    return view('bs_sidebar.interview_time', [
        'time' => $time
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Try using `@continue;` and removing the `else` statement (which is why your loop executes 35 times). Move the `<div>X</div>` _outside_ the `foreach`, remove the `else` and replace it with `@continue;`. This will function as you want. I've constructed [this](http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#dFTiEGOF) to show the idea, hope it helps.

Comment: @camelCase - I might be wrong, but won't that output X on each `for` iteration, regardless if it outputted 0 inside the `foreach`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes, but it's only reached if the `$value->time !== $i` due to the `@continue;`. I _think_ this is what the OP is looking for but not quite sure.

Comment: @camelCase - I still think you will get a `X` too many. @Bruce, what is the point of this loop and values? There must be another way to do what you are trying to do? What does the `$time` contain and ...  well... what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you might be right...but I've made a little [fiddle](http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#dFTiEGOF) that spits out what is listed in the question correctly...however as you're stating, it might not actually be what the OP is truly looking for.

Comment: Please show what data $time contains

Comment: @camelCase thanks your reply, but I try this sample http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#JjXZhiHJ
if $time  =  $i has 2 or more ,  The result will be more than seven loop..

Comment: @Insomania
my $time is database 
example: $time = [1,3,5,12,19.......];
so if $i  = $time   output  O     else   output X  , total  loop 7  times

Comment: Ah indeed it will. Didn't try alternatives, sorry! The others are right that there should be a better way to handle, hope you resolve soon.

Comment: @camelCase thank you very much~!  I try others way

Comment: i have added an answer, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    $check = 0;
    @foreach($time as $value)

        @if($value->time == $i)
            <?php
                $check = 1;
            ?>
            @break 
        @endif

    @endforeach
    @if $check == 1
        <div>O</div>
    @else
        <div>X</div>
    @endif
@endfor
```

so this way, the loop will only run 7 times,

please give it a try and let me know if it helps you

Thanks.

Comment: thank you answer, I try this 
http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#QRQAIFRf
the loop will only run 7 times, but foreach only loop 1 times, other value is not view

Comment: if  $time = [ 1 , 2 , 4] 
example output :  X O O X O X X

Comment: i have updated my answer, now check, this must help you

Comment: Thanks your reply! 
http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#MJWWHbai
but foreah 1 others all change O..

Comment: yes there was a mistake, sorry for that,  just updated it again, now check :)

Comment: i have tested it, http://www.bencomeau.com/projects/phpFiddle/fiddle.html#gTCAWAQj it's all working now, please try it

Answer (score 2):

```
   @for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
@foreach($time as $value)
    @if($value['time'] == $i)
        <?php
            $flag = 0;
        ?>
        @break
    @else
        <?php
        $flag = 1;
        ?>
    @endif
    @break
@endforeach
@if($flag==0)
    <div>O</div>
@else
    <div>X</div>
@endif
@endfor
```

Comment: Agarwala
thanks your answers!  but foreach $time is only loop 1 times, others value is not loop show.

Comment: if  $time = [ 1 , 2 , 4] 
example output :  X O O X O X X